# Dont't evaluate $config variable

Tags: php

I am trying to write a config file. which will contain an Array of options and the array name will be
`$config`. ut as the code is executed I get en error message that `Undefined variable: config`

I want that $cofig should be written in the file as it is instead of evaluating it.

```
$config_text = <<<FILECONTENT
<?php


$config = array(
    'Settings' => array(
        'SHOP_TITLE' => $this->request->data['Shop']['shop_name'] . ' - ' . $this->request->data['Shop']['admin_password'],
        'SHOP_ID' => $shop_id,
        'ANALYTICS' => '',
        'PAYPAL_API_USERNAME' => '',
        'PAYPAL_API_PASSWORD' => '',
        'PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE' => '',
        'AUTHORIZENET_ENABLED' => '1',
        'AUTHORIZENET_API_URL' => 'https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll',
        'AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN' => '',
        'AUTHORIZENET_API_TRANSACTION_KEY' => '',
    )    
);
;
FILECONTENT;
```

Comment: Use a NOWDOC instead of a HEREDOC?  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc  `<<<'FILECONTENT'`  Do you want the entire expression written to file without evaluating any of it, or did you want `$this->request->data['Shop']['shop_name']` to be evaluated?

Comment: $this->request->data['Shop']['shop_name'] should be evaluated.

Comment: You can't have the best of both worlds in one lump. You'll have to build your text in pieces.

Comment: @user160820 Never saw any additional comment from you. Do these solutions meet your need?

Answer (score 1):

#### The clever way with `var_export()`:

To force the expressions inside to be evaluated first but still produce output in a PHP code-parseable format,  actually define the array temporarily so it *is* evaluated into a variable, then call [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) on that variable, together with the `$config =` assignment to place it into a string.

```
// Actually create and evaluate a real array:
$defined_config = array(
    'Settings' => array(
        'SHOP_TITLE' => $this->request->data['Shop']['shop_name'] . ' - ' . $this->request->data['Shop']['admin_password'],
        'SHOP_ID' => $shop_id,
        'ANALYTICS' => '',
        'PAYPAL_API_USERNAME' => '',
        'PAYPAL_API_PASSWORD' => '',
        'PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE' => '',
        'AUTHORIZENET_ENABLED' => '1',
        'AUTHORIZENET_API_URL' => 'https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll',
        'AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN' => '',
        'AUTHORIZENET_API_TRANSACTION_KEY' => '',
    )    
);

// Export it to a parseable format, passing `true` as the second arg
// so it returns the string
$defined_config_text = var_export($defined_config, true);

// Then create the text variable as a HEREDOC or double-quoted string. You will have to escape the opening `$`.
// This does it with a HEREDOC, so the variable is internally parsed.
$config_text = <<<FILECONTENT
<?php
\$config = {$defined_config_text}
;
FILECONTENT;
```

You can then throw away the `$defined_config` array if unneeded:

```
unset($defined_config);
```

While this works in my own PHP interpreter, I'm having a difficult time getting an online interpreter to work correctly for demonstration purposes because of the `<?php` in the output.  Here's a partially working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/XG6ySt which omits the `<?php`.

#### The ugly brute-force string concatenation way:

Your other option, which is more straightforward to setup but far uglier looking is to merely concatenate in the expressions into a single-quoted string to produce valid PHP code.

```
// Create a big ugly string into which the expressions like 
// $this->request->data and $shop_id are concatenated
$config_text = '
<?php
$config = array(
     "Settings" => array(
            "SHOP_TITLE" => ' . $this->request->data['Shop']['shop_name'] . ' - ' . $this->request->data['Shop']['admin_password'] . ',
            "SHOP_ID" => ' . $shop_id . ',
            "ANALYTICS" => "",
            //etc....
      )
);
';
// ^^ Do not forget to close the single-quoted string and terminate ;
// Now your output string is complete in $config_text.
```